# Why am I getting $digest () iterations reached? How can I track my recursive script's activity?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, counter, watch

I am trying to understand my recursive script, which it acting inefficient.

I tried creating counters that will tell me how many times its been called and from where, so I could better understand it's behaviour. However, I am getting errors in the console that it's overloading the amount of iterations it can call:

```
Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function (context) {\n          for(var i = 0, ii = length, part; i<ii; i++) {\n            if (typeof (part = parts[i]) == 'function') {\n  .........
```

After doing extensive reading, I have a strong feeling it has to do with Angular recalculating everything each time it updates the counter, which `$watch` sees as a a change, sparking a new `$digest` round. Is this correct?

If so, how can I implement a counter on my recursive script?

To provide an example extremely similar to what I am trying to do, I forked a JSFiddle by [ganarajpr](http://jsfiddle.net/ganarajpr/vzvmS/3/) and added to it [here: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzvmS/537/).

As Stackoverflow demands, the Code is replicated below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{incrementCounter()}}
    {{data.name}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>

</ul>
    <h3> Counter {{counter}}</h3>
</div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.incrementCounter = function () {
        console.log("Increment called");
        $scope.counter++;
        document.counter++;
    }
}]);
app.controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.delete = function (data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function (data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({
            name: newName,
            nodes: []
        });
    };
    $scope.tree = [{
        name: "Node",
        nodes: []
    }];
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `$digest` cycle your `{{incrementCounter()}}` causes `{{counter}}` to change which causes a new `$digest` cycle which causes another evaluation of `{{incrementCounter()}}` ad infinitum. Basically if you have a counter which is incremented every `$digest` cycle, you can't have that variable affect the result of any `$watch`ed expression.

You'll need to make an alternative to `{{counter}}` which doesn't lean on the result of a `$watch` expression (e.g. write directly to the element).

Comment: My first reaction was to keep the counter out of the model; the potential issue being if there are multiple trees on the same page, which could still be handled by non-scoped counters.

Comment: "You'll need to make an alternative to `{{counter}}`" Any suggestions?

Comment: You could trigger an event (`scope.$emit` or `scope.$broadcast`) with the counter value in your `incrementCounter` function, then create a directive which listens (`scope.$on`) for that event and updates the element contents directly into the DOM (`elem.text(...)`).